# Is there any way to increase the maximum amount of file descriptors that select() can handle on Windows? _setmaxstdio doesn't affect it

Tags: python, windows, sockets, winsock, file-descriptor

For context, I'm writing an application in Python that needs to poll many hosts continuously, so I create a large number of sockets to communicate with those hosts. However, I can only create 511 sockets - when I try to create 512, I get a `ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()`. I thought this error was referencing the maximum amount of file descriptors that a process can have open at any given time, but when I try increasing that maximum with Python's `win32file._setmaxstdio()`, it has no effect - no matter what I set the limit to, I can only create 511 sockets. I even tried setting the limit to a value lower than 512 just to see if it would change anything, but I could still create 511 sockets! So as far as I can tell, the limits referenced by `_setmaxstdio()` and `_getmaxstdio()` are completely unrelated to the limit to how many sockets/file descriptors `select()` can handle.

I tried investigating Python's `select` module to see if I could find where `select()`'s maximum is defined, or how to increase it. [Python's documentation for the `select.select()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) doesn't mention either of those things, but it does mention that `select()` comes from Windows' Winsock library. So I checked [Microsoft's documentation of the `select()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select):

> Four macros are defined in the header file Winsock2.h for manipulating and checking the descriptor sets. **The variable FD_SETSIZE determines the maximum number of descriptors in a set. (The default value of FD_SETSIZE is 64**, which can be modified by defining FD_SETSIZE to another value before including Winsock2.h.)

I read this to mean "`select()` can handle 64 sockets by default, but you can change that by altering the value of `FD_SETSIZE` before you include the header file". So I assume Python sets it to 512 before including the Winsock2 header file? Or is `select()`'s limit set some other way?

I just want to know where the `select()` function's limit is defined, how I can check it, and if it can be increased from within Python, but I'm clearly missing something fundamental here. `select()` can handle some number of file descriptors, and `_setmaxstdio()` is used to "[set] a maximum for the number of simultaneously open files at the stream I/O level", but changing the limit with `_setmaxstdio()` doesn't affect the limit for `select()`. Why not? If `select()` isn't limited by the maximum amount of file descriptors you're allowed to have, then what is it limited by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days later, my best understanding of the situation is this: the per-process limit to number of file descriptors IS controlled by `_setmaxstdio()`, and I was using it correctly, BUT that upper limit set by `_setmaxstdio()` does not apply if you use the `select()` function, because `select()` has a hardcoded limit. In order for the limit you set with `_setmaxstdio()` to have an actual effect, you must use `poll()`, `epoll()`, etc., instead of `select()`. And if there *is* a way to increase the limits of the `select()` function, it seems like you need to recompile part of Windows' C runtime, which is not a good idea. Since I have the option to drop support for Windows and only support Unix instead, I'd much rather just do it that way.

If you're reading this answer because you want to increase the limits of Windows' `select()` function, and like me, you are new to the concept of file descriptors/completion ports, and haven't extensively worked with sockets before, and don't want to/don't know how to screw around with the C runtime (CRT), I suggest you first consider the following before continuing trying to alter the `select()` limit:

- Can you use `poll()` or `epoll()` instead of `select()`? In my case, the only reason I was using `select()` is because I was locked into because of the libraries I'm using - asyncio and psycopg. At the time of writing, psycopg does **not** support asyncio's `ProactorEventLoop` in Windows, so I was forced to instead use the `SelectorEventLoop` (which uses `select()`) instead of the default `ProactorEventLoop`, which doesn't use `select()`. However, psycopg has no such limitation in Unix - it will work with any asyncio event loop there. So if you can use `poll()`, `epoll()`, etc instead of `select()`, then that's probably a lot easier than trying to *actually* increase the `select()` limit since then you'll be able to just use `_setmaxstdio()` to set the file descriptor limit, and it'll actually let you have more file descriptors.

Instead of continuing to try to make this work with Windows, I'm just going to use Unix instead - I probably should have done that from the beginning since it's a backend kind of process, but the convenience of being able to run/test/debug the code directly on my development machine was tempting, and I *thought* that the added flexibility of supporting both Windows and Unix would be worth the (what I thought would be minimal) overhead of adding `if os is Windows use SelectorEventLoop` to the start of my application.